# Can i extend @Context annotation work scope in jax-rs

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

I have jax-rs project where i have my own classes. @Context annotation don`t inject at that classes. How can i extend @Context annotation work for injection at my classes ?
Thanks!

`@Provider
public class MyOwnClass
{
   @Context
   HttpServletRequest request ; // variable request equal null all the time
}`

Comment: Could you please state what you're trying to achieve. Your question suggests your approach may be inadvisable.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the ansver. My situation in code below
    class MyOwnClass
    {
        @Context
        HttpServletRequest request ;
        // request equal null all time
    }

Comment: I try @Provider annotation on MyOwnClass, it`s a same don`t work. @Provider class MyOwnClass { @Context HttpServletRequest request ; // request equal null all time }

Answer (score 0):

`@Provider` will not mark your class a resource class. Swap it for `@Path`.